# Sequelize column reference is ambiguous

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to accomplish the task of joining all associated models, and then retrieving the count of all the models
I would want the data to be returned as

```
product {
   main_dish: {},
   side_dish: {},
   drink: {},
   purchase_product_count: x,
   purchased_products: []
}
```

I have constructed this in sequelize to try to do this.

```
     await Product.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: MainCourse,
            required: false,
        }, {
            model: SideDish,
            required: false,
        }, {
            model: Drink,
            required: false,
        }, {
            model: ProductPurchase,
            required: false,
            where: {
                createdAt: {[Op.between]: [two_days_before, current_date]}
            },
        }],
        attributes: {
            include: ['*', 
                [Sequelize.literal(
                    "(SELECT COUNT(*) from product_purchases as p where p.purchase_product_id = products.product_id)"), "product_purchase_count"],
            ]
        },
        offset: 1 * 5,
        limit: 5
    })
    .then((results) => {
        console.log(results)
        res.status(200).json(results)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(400).json(err)
    })
```

Attempting to run this eager load gives this error

```
column reference "product_id" is ambiguous
```

This is the sql generated by sequelize

```
SELECT "products".*, "main_course"."main_course_id" AS "main_course.main_course_id", "main_course"."type" AS "main_course.type", "main_course"."createdAt" AS "main_course.createdAt", "main_course"."updatedAt" AS "main_course.updatedAt", "main_course"."deletedAt" AS "main_course.deletedAt", "main_course"."main_product_id" AS "main_course.main_product_id", "side_dish"."side_dish_id" AS "side_dish.side_dish_id", "side_dish"."type" AS "side_dish.type", "side_dish"."createdAt" AS "side_dish.createdAt", "side_dish"."updatedAt" AS "side_dish.updatedAt", "side_dish"."deletedAt" AS "side_dish.deletedAt", "side_dish"."side_product_id" AS "side_dish.side_product_id", "drink"."drink_id" AS "drink.drink_id", "drink"."type" AS "drink.type", "drink"."createdAt" AS "drink.createdAt", "drink"."updatedAt" AS "drink.updatedAt", "drink"."deletedAt" AS "drink.deletedAt", "drink"."drink_product_id" AS "drink.drink_product_id", "product_purchases"."product_purchase_id" AS "product_purchases.product_purchase_id", "product_purchases"."price" AS "product_purchases.price", "product_purchases"."quantity" AS "product_purchases.quantity", "product_purchases"."createdAt" AS "product_purchases.createdAt", "product_purchases"."updatedAt" AS "product_purchases.updatedAt", "product_purchases"."deletedAt" AS "product_purchases.deletedAt", "product_purchases"."purchase_product_id" AS "product_purchases.purchase_product_id", "product_purchases"."restaurant_order_id" AS "product_purchases.restaurant_order_id" FROM (SELECT "products"."product_id", "products"."title", "products"."price", "products"."createdAt", "products"."updatedAt", "products"."deletedAt", "products"."restaurant_id", "products".*, (SELECT COUNT(*) from product_purchases as p where p.purchase_product_id = products.product_id) AS "product_purchase_count" FROM "products" AS "products" WHERE ("products"."deletedAt" IS NULL) LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5) AS "products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "main_courses" AS "main_course" ON "products"."product_id" = "main_course"."main_product_id" AND ("main_course"."deletedAt" IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN "side_dishes" AS "side_dish" ON "products"."product_id" = "side_dish"."side_product_id" AND ("side_dish"."deletedAt" IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN "drinks" AS "drink" ON "products"."product_id" = "drink"."drink_product_id" AND ("drink"."deletedAt" IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_purchases" AS "product_purchases" ON "products"."product_id" = "product_purchases"."purchase_product_id" AND ("product_purchases"."deletedAt" IS NULL AND "product_purchases"."createdAt" BETWEEN '2022-05-06 08:35:12.577 +00:00' AND '2022-05-08 08:35:12.577 +00:00');
```

According to pgadmin the problem starts when doing the join on main_courses

```
ERROR:  column reference "product_id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...EFT OUTER JOIN "main_courses" AS "main_course" ON "products"...
```

I seem to not understand how the sequelize join works as I am using the ORM method of not having any columns be the same. The foreign keys are all different from 'product_id'. Is product_id getting created and joined again on the aggregation possibly? Why am I getting this error, and how can I achieve the result of getting the count of the product_purchases along with the joined array of purchased products.

Obviously I could just get the purchased_products.length and then add it to the object itself, but I'm trying to figure out if you can do it through sequelize without having to hack it in.

Comment: You need to indicate `attributes: []` for all includes

Comment: @Anatoly not solve ...         {
          model: user,
          paranoid: false,
          attributes: [],
        }, because i display on the table with model full_name but in user have same column that name is full_name , the error came to me when implementation to search  / keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Two tables having the same column name?:

Specify the `Table.columnName` that the query is preferred for.

See example query below:

```
//this is typescript, using Sequelize.
const result = await Table.findAll({ where: { 
 [Op.and]:[
  {
          Sequelize.where(
      Sequelize.cast(Sequelize.col("PreferredTable.columnName"), "TEXT"),
      {
        [Op.like]: `%${columnName}%`,
      }
    )

  }
 ]
} });
```

Notice the preference to cast `columnName` to TEXT, use your own preferred setup, but the approach is basically the same.